# Two-factor authentication for Windows, trackable key linked to ActiveDirectory (alternative to AuthLite)

Tags: security, authentication

Does anyone know of a good alternative to AuthLite as a two-factor authentication for PCs and laptops?

Requirements:

- Reliable, i.e. works 98% or more of the time
- Works with some sort of trackable key fob that can be linked to the user's ActiveDirectory account.
- We don't want a card reader setup either as they tend to be cumbersome.

We are having a lot of issues with [AuthLite](http://www.collectivesoftware.com/solutions/authlite) as of late, not allowing user access even though the user is doing everything correct, kind of stuff. It seems this is directly related to updating the client version often. My company has a lot of software techs that need to go onsite and, with a few costumers, this can be a real hassle to fix a login issue related to AuthLite when the costumer is breathing down the neck of our tech wondering why something is taking so long and unwilling to understand that technical difficulties actually happen. The other factor is we have to have a two-factor authentication to access our PCs due to CJIS sensitive access thus why we have AuthLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I work for AuthLite, but am attempting an unbiased helpful answer anyway)

## Software recommendation:

To see what else is out there, and also to keep your investment in YubiKeys, you may want to go through the list of [Yubico Enterprise Partners](https://www.yubico.com/support/partners/) to check their offerings.  Also have a look at [Rohos Logon Key](http://www.rohos.com/products/rohos-logon-key/) which is one of our original competitors for YubiKey logon to Windows desktops, so has a long history.

Reason for recommending above: OP already has purchased YubiKeys, and wants to keep using a trackable hardware key, and needs it to work on Windows.

## Additional discussion about the original problem:

Most of the 2.1 client version updates were related to changing the way the offline login caching works, specifically to improve the situation you are describing.  But based on your ticket history and this post, I conclude you must be still having problems with the new 2.1.13 build which you haven't reported to us, and are fed up trying to work on it.

I feel bad that it progressed to that point; if you end up stopping use of AuthLite, please contact us and let's see if we can get you some amount of refund.  Even though it does not fix the lost time you have already experienced, it would at least be a token of apology and give you some $ to defray the cost of your next 2F solution.

While you are checking into new solutions, if you would like to continue troubleshooting what's going on with your workstations then we would be more than happy to help.  Please continue with your current support ticket or open a new one.

Either way, sorry again this has progressed to the point where you're looking to jump ship, and I hope you can find a resolution that works well on your systems.

~Greg / Collective Software,
(vendor of AuthLite, and embarrassed)

Comment: I can't say that Authlite has been all bad. It worked well for us for awhile now. It just has caused us enough trouble as of late that the team, myself included, has had cause to want to weigh our options. I appreciate your answer though and I will take a look at what you suggest. At this time we aren't going away from Authlite but will look at other possibilities. Thank you again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Greg, and we all appreciate the way you address the *issue* -- but this site is about *software recommendations* as in "recommend a software to fit the requirements", which this answer doesn't meet. Can you [edit] your answer to [meet our rules](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/185)? If not, I'm sorry, this answer will be removed. You might leave a comment for Eddie on how to directly contact your team for the parts discussed (I volunteer to move that to the question then, as you still lack some rep to do so). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Izzy.  Did you see the first paragraph where I recommend a list of software vendors and then Rohos Logon Key?  Is this not specific enough?

Comment: I tried adding some info to clarify the recommendations, why I recommended them, and separate the rest of the post into a "more discussion" section.